# How to fix the motion_planning_rviz_plugin on Fuerte?

Tags: motion-planning, rviz, arm-navigation, ompl-ros-interface, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I really want to make rviz subscribe to arm_navigation_msgs::DisplayTrajectory and there is already a plugin for that:motion_planning_rviz_plugin in arm_navigation stack. Thanks!

However, there is a typo (an extra 'g') for the class field of class entry in its [plugin_description.xml](https://kforge.ros.org/armnavigation/armnavigation/file/1e25b730b303/motion_planning_rviz_plugin/plugin_description.xml) triggering the following error msg when adding Planning Display.

```
[ERROR] [1337924692.343620701]: The plugin for class 'motiong_planning_rviz_plugin/Planning' failed to load.  Error: Failed to load library /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/motion_planning_rviz_plugin/lib/libmotion_planning_rviz_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: No manifest in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/motion_planning_rviz_plugin/lib/libmotion_planning_rviz_plugin.so: motiong_planning_rviz_plugin__Planning
```

Based on what I understand from [this tutorial](http://ros.org/doc/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html), I naively corrected the name field of class entry in plugin_description.xml under /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/motion_planning_rviz_plugin.
But, I got a segfault when adding Planning Display (Rviz suddenly quit, badly with an *empty* rviz-*.log).

Still, have no idea why that trivial correction for a seemingly trivial typo in the .xml leads to a segfault.

Do I overlook something?

Thank you.

PS: This is related to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/33864/failed-to-load-motion_planning_rviz_pluginso/) and [this ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5444). Apologize for somewhat reposting.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34812/how-to-fix-the-motion_planning_rviz_plugin-on-fuerte?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-06-06**:
I can confirm this bug (including the segfault after the naive fix), but I don't know what to do about it. I've updated the relevant [bug](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5444) with a link to this question. Maybe the next step would be to email Gil Jones directly?

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-06-07**:
Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fix for both the type and the segfault released into arm_navigation 1.1.10 - it'll take a couple to get through the build farm and pushed into the public repos (it's already on ros-shadow-fixed for most distros).  Let me know if you encounter more problems.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on 2012-06-08**:
Thanks Gil.